# Collapse A UIImageView From A Center Point

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview, animatewithduration

I have a UIImageView that I want to scale its outter edges towards the center (the top and bottom edges to be precise). The best I am able to get so far is just one edge collapsing into the other (which doesn't move). I want both edges to collapse towards the middle.

I have tried setting the the anchor point to 0.5,0.5 but that doesnt address the issue (nothing changes).

Is there a way to setup an ImageView such that it will scale inwards towards the middle so the outter edges collapse towards the center?

Here was my best attempt:

```
override public func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        var uimg = UIImage(named: "img.PNG")!
        var img:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: uimg)
        img.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
        view.addSubview(img)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(5, animations:
            { () -> Void in
                img.frame = CGRectMake(img.frame.origin.x,img.frame.origin.y,img.frame.width, 0)
            })
            { (finished) -> Void in
                //
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting transform on imageView. Scale it to (1, 0), vertically zero.

Comment: That is what I am doing the problem is its not scaling from the middle

Comment: Where are you scaling, you are setting the frame of the imageView, as you have shown in the code above.

Comment: `img.frame = CGRectMake(img.frame.origin.x,img.frame.origin.y,img.frame.width, 0)`

Comment: img.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 0), use this

Comment: Hmm that doesnt seem to work inside of an animateWithDuration call

Comment: Ok, 0 does not work, make it as small as possible but greater than 0, such as 0.01 and that does work.

Comment: Yes that can do the trick decently enough without having to reposition it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scaling using UIView's transform property. It seems like scaling does not allow you to make the value 0 and it goes to the final value without any animation. So, you could basically make the scaling y value negligible like 0.001.

```
   imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 0.001)
```

You could also use core animation to scale, using CABasicAnimation, this would be more simpler as this,

```
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.y")
    animation.toValue = 0
    animation.duration = 2.0
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.removedOnCompletion = false
    imageView.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "anim")
```

Or you can also use the approach you have been using, simply setting the frame,

```
    var finalFrame = imageView.frame
    finalFrame.size.height = 0

    finalFrame.origin.y = imageView.frame.origin.y + (imageView.frame.size.height / 2)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.imageView.frame = finalFrame
    })
```

Comment: Very curious why scaling occurs from its middle!

Comment: Scaling does not reposition the position property of layer, it simply sets scales the layer and so it remains in the same position, but stretches or compresses the view.

Answer (score 1):

Your new frame has the origin in the same place.  You need to move the origin down, at the same time as you reduce the height:

```
img.frame = CGRectMake(img.frame.origin.x, img.frame.origin.y + (img.frame.size.height/2), img.frame.size.width, 0);
```

Comment: Yes I found this out by pure experimentation but I dont understand WHY it behaves like this :/ In theory shouldnt it be moving down while still scaling the bottom to the top? Its counter intuitive!